# Как в сайдбаре задать блок(div)?

Tags: wordpress

Сайдбар > через виджет добавил 4 выпадающих меню и 2 записи. Можно ли как то объединить эти четыре менюшки в один блок(div) ?

```
    <?php if ( is_active_sidebar( 'sidebar-1' ) ) : ?>
    <div id="secondary" class="widget-area" role="complementary">
        <?php dynamic_sidebar( 'sidebar-1' ); ?>
    </div><!-- #secondary -->
<?php endif; ?>
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Вставьте в вопрос код из файла, который отвечает за вывод сайдбара, в вашем шаблоне.

Comment: @ВалерийЕмельянов вставил код

Answer (score 0):

Если я правильно понял, то будет выглядеть так (`div class="newdiv"`).

```
<?php if ( is_active_sidebar( 'sidebar-1' ) ) : ?>
    <div id="secondary" class="widget-area" role="complementary">
      <div class="newdiv">  <?php dynamic_sidebar( 'sidebar-1' ); ?></div>
    </div><!-- #secondary -->
<?php endif; ?>
```

Comment: Спасибо за такую запись, на будущее может понадобиться. Но вы наверно не так меня поняли. Весь сайдбар - это 4 меню и 2 записи. Вы сейчас просто опять засунули 6 элементов в див). Мне б как то только меню взять в див, записи трогать не нужно. Если я правильно понимаю, то такое осуществить нельзя

Comment: Теоритически возьми добавь еще два виджета "Текст". Один до менюшек, другой после. В первом пропиши открытие дива, а в последнем закрытие. Но я за это не ручаюсь )